# Modern Core Data Performance with UUID

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, core-data, uuid

I have a Core Data application with:

- 549 Account entities with myJournals relationship (one to many)
- 24000 Ledger entities with myJournals relationship (one to many)
- 57000 Journal entities with myAccount and myLedger (one to one) inverse
  relationship

Each entity has a uuidKey string attribute with a UUID string imported from an online database.

I'm trying to run the app on an iPhone 5S. Inserting objects is relatively fast, but finding and linking the relationships is longer than anticipated.

```
let debugTime = NSDate()
let thisRequest = NSFetchRequest(entityName: "Ledgers")
let keyLeft = NSExpression(forKeyPath: "uuidKey")
let keyRight = NSExpression(forConstantValue: ledgerKey)
let keyPredicate = NSComparisonPredicate(leftExpression: keyLeft, rightExpression: keyRight, modifier: NSComparisonPredicateModifier.DirectPredicateModifier, type: NSPredicateOperatorType.EqualToPredicateOperatorType, options: NSComparisonPredicateOptions.allZeros)
thisRequest.predicate = keyPredicate
thisRequest.fetchBatchSize = 1
thisRequest.fetchLimit = 1
println("DEBUG COMMENT: \(debugTime.timeIntervalSinceNow) time to create thisRequest.")
var keyError: NSError? = nil
if let keyArray = self.managedObjectContext!.executeFetchRequest(thisRequest, error: &keyError) {
    if keyArray.isEmpty {
        myLedger = nil
    } else {
        if let thisLedger = keyArray[0] as? Ledgers {
            println("DEBUG COMMENT: \(debugTime.timeIntervalSinceNow) time to find thisLedger.")
            myLedger = thisLedger
        } else {
            myLedger = nil
        }
    }
}
println("DEBUG COMMENT: \(debugTime.timeIntervalSinceNow) time to link myLedger.")
```

I get log times like this:

```
DEBUG COMMENT: -9.20295715332031e-05 time to create thisRequest.
DEBUG COMMENT: -0.174275994300842 time to find thisLedger.
DEBUG COMMENT: -0.174659013748169 time to link myLedger.
DEBUG COMMENT: -0.00464397668838501 time to find and link myAccount.
```

0.092 milliseconds to create the NSFetchRequest is fine.
174 milliseconds to find the Ledger? On an indexed UUID string when there are 24k Ledgers?!? When I need to link this to 57k Journals?

Faster is always better. 4 milliseconds to find a link myAccount when there are 549 accounts is slightly disappointing but acceptable. For the Ledger search I was expecting about 25-50 milliseconds, not 174!

I'm running this in its own core data store and context:

```
    // Initialize the persistent store coordinator for the sync session.
    let url = appDel.applicationDocumentsDirectory.URLByAppendingPathComponent("FoodyCoreModel.sqlite")
    self.syncStore = NSPersistentStoreCoordinator(managedObjectModel: appDel.managedObjectModel)
    var error: NSError? = nil
    var failureReason = "There was an error creating or loading the application's saved data."
    let storeOptions: [NSObject: AnyObject] = [NSMigratePersistentStoresAutomaticallyOption: true, NSInferMappingModelAutomaticallyOption: true]
    self.syncStore.addPersistentStoreWithType(NSSQLiteStoreType, configuration: nil, URL: url, options: storeOptions, error: &error)

    // Initialize the managed object contextfor the sync session
    self.syncContext = NSManagedObjectContext(concurrencyType: NSManagedObjectContextConcurrencyType.PrivateQueueConcurrencyType)
    self.syncContext.persistentStoreCoordinator = self.syncStore
    let nmp = NSMergePolicy(mergeType: NSMergePolicyType.MergeByPropertyStoreTrumpMergePolicyType)
    self.syncContext.mergePolicy = nmp
```

Is this reasonable performance to expect with an iPhone 5S? I've read many of the Core Data performance questions here, but many of them date from years ago. I was hoping that iOS 8 and more recent devices would be significantly faster. I'm not trying to do a MATCHES or CONTAINS search, just EQUALS on an indexed text field!

I've read the  [Core Data Performance Guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CoreData/Articles/cdPerformance.html). Is there something I'm missing or am I just expecting too much from a mobile device?

Comment: P.S. Search performance seems to get significantly worse with any Entity type that has more than 15000 rows. Anyone else notice this?

Comment: Have you read this... from The Pragmatic Bookshelf – "Core Data, 2nd Edition, Data Storage and Management for iOS, OS X, and iCloud" (Jan 2013) by Marcus S. Zarra, and in particular Chapter 4 titled "Performance Tuning”. Also, and forgive me this is just a guess, but have you tried switching the left and right joins?

Comment: Most of the Ledgers have two Journals. Querying from each Ledger (Ledger.uuidKey == Journal.uuidLedger) doesn't seem any faster than the other way around.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The most likely slowdown in your code is that you're fetching `Ledger` instances one at a time, and you say there are 24,000 of them. That's going to be a major bottleneck no matter what. Fetching is a relatively expensive operation, regardless of whether you're using a string ID in the predicate, so your code is going to be spending most of its time fetching.

You should be fetching in batches instead of one at a time. Collect 50 or 100 or so `uuidKey` values into an array and use a predicate format like `"uuidKey in %@"` with the array as the substitution variable. Process that batch, and repeat until done.

For more detail on how to import data efficiently, refer to Apple's ["Efficiently Importing Data"](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CoreData/Articles/cdImporting.html) guide, especially the section called "Implementing Find-or-Create Efficiently".

As an aside, using `println` like this is a really poor way to measure performance. Use Instruments. It'll give you more detail with less overhead and without cluttering up your code, and will help you nail down exactly where bottlenecks are.

Comment: The Ledgers were already imported. Then I start downloading Journals, 1000 at a time. I did use a uuidKey in to compare Journals with what is already in the database. A dict of uuidKey: JSON for all 1000. A set of all 1000 journalKeys. A set of matching journal keys. Loop through and compare dateModified to see what is unchanged vs updated. Subtract unchanged and updated from all keys to get the Journals to insert. As I've said in my original question, I've read Efficiently Importing Data. Part of my mistake seems to be setting the relations one at a time. I'll have to see how much memory...

Comment: You're still fetching Ledgers one at a time, which is still likely to be the main performance problem.

Comment: ... I'll have to see how much memory a dict [uuidKeyString: NSManagedObjectID] of all of the Ledgers takes.